# How to make this assertion pass

Tags: scala

I am confused as to how to do this. I need to convert it to String. I tried `x.toString` but it doesn't see to work.

```
def doSomething(x: Int, function: Int => String): String = ???

assert(doSomething(5, (i: Int) => i.toString) == "5")
assert(doSomething(7, (i: Int) => (i + 5).toString) == "12")
```

Comment: where is your implementation of ```doSomething``` ? ```???``` is just a placeholder for a missing implementation. Or are you asking how it should be implemented?

Comment: You just need to apply `function` to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to actually *call* or apply the function... as in:

```
def doSomething(x: Int, function: Int => String): String = function(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `def doSomething(x: Int, function: Int => String): String = function(x)`, `???` is just a placeholder in Scala.